# Реализация HalfEdge с использованием std::vector

Tags: алгоритм, графика, halfedge, dcel

Мне нужно создать HalfEdge по такому скелету:

```
struct HalfEdgeHandle { int64_t index = -1; };
struct VertexHandle { int64_t index = -1; };
struct FaceHandle { int64_t index = -1; };

struct HalfEdge
{ 
    //The face it belongs to, is invalid (== -1) if a boundary half-edge 
    FaceHandle fh; 
    //The vertex it points to is always valid VertexHandle dst;       
    //The twin half-edge is always VALID. Even for boundary half-edges! 
    HalfEdgeHandle twin; 
    //The next HalfEdge in the CCW order is always valid
    НalfEdgeHandle next;
    //The previous HalfEdge in the CCW order can be stored for the optimization purposes.
    HalfEdgeHandle prev; 
};

struct Face{ 
    //One of the HalfEdges belonging to the Face, always valid
    HalfEdgeHandle heh;
};

struct Vertex{ 
    //An outgoing HalfEdge from this vertex. It is == -1 if the vertex is isolated
    HalfEdgeHandle heh;
};
```

Данные у меня поступаю в треугольниках (по три вершины).
Правильно ли я понял, что, например, если ввести такой квадрат, то структура массивов должна быть такой или где-то у меня есть опечатки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В `HalfEdge` не хватает `VertexHandle start`.

Comment: В таблице у вас есть столбец `dst` который обозначает конец полуребра. Он может заменить `start` из предыдущего комментария. Вектор `vertices` лишний. Без него можно обойтись, вписав в `dst` индексы вектора `Points`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy verticesHe должен иметь только по одной вершине, которые ссылается на один любой исходящий halfedge?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А если у меня так: `HalfEdge::dst` содержаит индексы на points, а `verticesHE` содержит такоеже кол-во верщшин, как и кол-во точет и ссылается на любой одни исходящее HalfEdgeHadle. Это верно?

Comment: Я удалил ошибочный комментарий. Правильно так: `HalfEdge::dst` должен содержать индекс из `Points`. `VerticesHE` содержит одно исходящее полуребро и больше ничего (как сейчас и сделано). `vertices` не нужен вообще.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо вам огромное, уже не первый раз выручатете)